# WSO2 - simple endpoint fails

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup a simple API test against a local endpoint.  I have create the sample API (phone number lookup) and that works fine.

http://192.168.1.11:8080/api/simpleTest is my endpoint and the WSO2 service also runs on 192.168.1.11 ... but when I test it in 'publisher', it always fails.  This is a simple GET with no parameters.

I can run it from a browser or CURL (outside of WSO2) and it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: How you haved added the endpoint?

Comment: I am using a HTTP Endpoint definition, as a backend endpoint implementation method type.

Comment: What's your WSO2 API Manager version? Are you behind any proxies?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you talk about clicking the Test button when providing Backend Endpoint in API publisher.

The way that Test button works at the moment (as far as I understand) is that it invokes HTTP HEAD method on the endpoint provided (because according to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), "*This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.*")

Then it checks response. If response is valid or 405 (method not allowed), then the URL is marked as Valid.

Thus sometimes, if backend is not properly following RFC, you might get otherwise working URLs declared as Invalid during the test because of that improper HEAD response evaluation. Obviously, this is just a check for your convenience and you can ignore the check if you know the endpoint works for the methods and resources you need it to work.

P.S. Checked it on [API Cloud](http://cloud.wso2.com) but behavior is identical to downloadable API Manager.